# Does launching a kernel on the default stream "catch" it launch-time errors?

Tags: error-handling, cuda

When we launch a CUDA kernel on a stream, an error may occur as we submit it for launching (e.g.  `cudaErrorInitializationError`, `cudaErrorInsufficientDriver` or `cudaErrorNoDevice`); and an error may occur as the kernel executes (e.g. illegal memory access).

If we launch a kernel on the default stream of a device, or more generally on a synchronous stream - is the return value only guaranteed to "catch" only the launch errors proper, like with asynchronous launches? Or - is it guaranteed to also catch any error during the kernel's run?

Comment: kernel launches are always asynchronous, whatever stream you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, and it's even worse that that.

Empirically, launching on the default stream may succeed despite the kernel triggering an error. In fact, even something like:

```cuda
myKernel<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(whatever);
cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
```

may fail to produce the error code corresponding to what the kernel has done.As @talonmies indicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038590/681865), certainty in encountering the error requires either a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, or a blocking API call (such as `cudaMemcpy()`).